# Setting font style in javascript output

Tags: javascript, html

I am having troubles with formatting basic javascript output. Right now it is outputting in the generic times font, and I would like to change that to something like calibri.

Example:

```
var x = document.getElementById("textbox1").value;
document.print("<p style='font-family:calibri'>x</p>");
```

I'm aware that this doesn't work because it's treating it as a string literal and just outputs an x in calibri font. So how can I get it to output the variable x and keep the font formatting?

Must stay in javascript and html, can use CSS but am not very familiar at all with it.

Comment: I would recommend you read up on [CSS classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors) and use those instead of inline styles like you have now.

Comment: The link you have included includes HTML examples, but I am speaking in javascript output. I am new to both so perhaps I am misinterpreting it.

Comment: You're printing out HTML (the `<p ...>` thing). If you're not sure of exactly what I'm talking about, I'd *seriously* recommend spending some time learning more about them before trying to use them. [Something like this](http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/htmlcss)

Comment: It looks like you're interested in learning _String concatenation_ in _JavaScript_. In _JavaScript_ this is handled by the [addition operator, `+`](http://es5.github.io/#x11.6.1)

Comment: That was the trick Paul, I wasn't aware of how Strings worked with the HTML being within the document.print method.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it's being treated as a string literal is because it is one.

```
var x = document.getElementById("textbox1").value;
document.print("<p style='font-family:calibri'>x</p>");
```

If you want the #textbox's value to appear you'll need this:

```
var x = document.getElementById("textbox1").value;
document.print("<p style='font-family:calibri'>"+x+"</p>");
```

Basically, that ties the three strings together, as + is an operator that not only will calculate

```
alert(1 + 1)
```

Which would come out as the integer 2

But also

```
'Hi.'+" I'm Jeff."
```

Which would come out as the string "Hi. I'm Jeff."

Comment: Thank you for your help. I wasn't aware that the <p></p> would stay intact through the entire function, I thought that they had to be enclosed in the same set of quotations.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use *String concatenation* at all to achieve this as you want to set the text contents of an element to exactly the *String* you've obtained

---

In your *StyleSheet* (i.e. between `<style>` and `</style>`),

```css
.some_awesome_description {
    font-family: calibri;
}
```

*The `.` before the token here specifies "look for this in the class attribute"*

In your *JavaScript*,

```js
// get your String
var x = document.getElementById("textbox1").value;

// create a new element
var my_awesome_element = document.createElement('span');

// set it's text as the String
my_awesome_element.textContent = x;

// set it's class to be matched by the CSS
my_awesome_element.setAttribute('class', 'some_awesome_description');

// append it to the DOM tree where you want it
document.body.appendChild(my_awesome_element);
```

Things we used

- *method* [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) to create a new element
- *property* [`node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) to set the text of an element
- *method* [`element.setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) to create an attribute on an element
- *method* [`node.appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) to add an element to the DOM tree
- `document.body`, the standard way to reference the `<body>` of a *HTML #document*
- [`<span>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span), a generic inline container element

Comment: This is very helpful thank you! So the CSS just goes in the head of my HTML correct? Or do I have to format it differently to use in the HTML? The only time I've used CSS it was in an external file.

Comment: @Burninrock24 you can put CSS in three places: 1) inline (as you did when you used `style="foo: bar;"`), 2) inside a `<style>` tag in the `<head>` section of your HTML document as Paul explained, and 3) in an external CSS file using `<link rel="stylesheet">` as you described.

Answer (score 0):

Separate the `x` from the strings with your `<p>` and [concatenate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Description) (`+`):

```
var x = document.getElementById("textbox1").value;
document.write("<p style='font-family:calibri'>" + x + "</p>");
```

Comment: `print` isn't a method of _#document_

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know the dynamics of how that worked with string variables.